# ¿Como puedo eliminar el texto dentro de un div que contiene otros divs drag-n-drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un `div` el cual contiene un "texto" que dice "Arrastre los items aquí"  quisiera eliminarlos cuando el contenedor tenga 1 o más de un `div` internos.

```js
function dragstart(caja, event) {
  // el elemento a arrastrar
  //console.log("dragstart");
  event.dataTransfer.setData('Data', caja.id);
}

function drag(target, event) {
  //console.log("drag");
  return false;
}

function dragend(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragend");
  return false;
}

function dragenter(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragenter");
  return false;
}

function dragleave(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragleave");
  return false;
}

function dragover(event) {
  //console.log("dragover");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function drop(target, event) {
  // obtenemos los datos
  var caja = event.dataTransfer.getData('Data');
  // agregamos el elemento de arrastre al contenedor
  target.appendChild(document.getElementById(caja));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Listado de Procesos</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_princ" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
      <div id="caja_1" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Mezcla" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_6" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="No Se" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_5" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Etiquetado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_4" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Vaciado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_3" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Llenado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_2" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Esterilizacion" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Contenedor 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_2" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dejo este código que hace lo que tu quieres y esta un poco mejor organizado

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  function bindEvents(){
    let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.cont');
    for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
      containers[i].addEventListener('dragstart',function(event){
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Data', event.target.id);
      })
      containers[i].addEventListener('dragover',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      })
      containers[i].addEventListener('drop',function(event){
        let cajaId = event.dataTransfer.getData('Data');
        let caja = document.getElementById(cajaId);
        this.appendChild(caja);
        actualizarTexto();
      })
    }
  }

    document.getElementById('addCont').addEventListener('click',function(){
      let newCont = document.createElement('div');
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = 'Arraste los items aqui';
      newCont.classList.add('cont');
      newCont.appendChild(span);
      document.getElementById('box-body').appendChild(newCont);
      bindEvents();
    })

    function actualizarTexto(){
      let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.cont');
      for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
        let numCajas = containers[i].querySelectorAll('.caja').length;
        if(numCajas < 1){
          containers[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Arrastre los items aqui';
        } else {
          containers[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = '';
        }
      }
    }

    bindEvents();
})
```

```css
.caja {
   background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183);
   border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183);
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   position: relative;
}

.cont {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: dotted 1px #000;
}

#addCont{
  margin: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Listado de Procesos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div id="contenedor_princ" class="cont"><span></span>
          <div id="caja_1" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="Mezcla" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
          <div id="caja_6" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="No Se" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
          <div id="caja_5" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="Etiquetado" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
          <div id="caja_4" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="Vaciado" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
          <div id="caja_3" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="Llenado" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
          <div id="caja_2" class="col-md-12" draggable="true">
            <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle caja" value="Esterilizacion" readonly="true" disable="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h4 class="box-title">Contenedor 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body" id="box-body">
        <div id="contenedor_2" class="cont"><span>Arrastre los items aquí</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Agregar Contenedor" id="addCont">
  </body>
</html>
```

Puedes generar contenedores de forma dinámica y si estos están vacíos aparece el texto "Arrastre los ítems aquí"

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer una modificación a la función drop para validar el numero de divs que ya se han añadido, y cambiar el texto a una etiqueta span para que sea mas fácil modificarla, ademas hacer que cuando la cantidad de ítems sea 0 volver a añadir el texto

```js
function dragstart(caja, event) {
  // el elemento a arrastrar
  //console.log("dragstart");
  event.dataTransfer.setData('Data', caja.id);
}

function drag(target, event) {
  //console.log("drag");
  return false;
}

function dragend(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragend");
  return false;
}

function dragenter(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragenter");
  return false;
}

function dragleave(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragleave");
  return false;
}

function dragover(event) {
  //console.log("dragover");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function drop(target, event) {
  // obtenemos los datos
  var caja = event.dataTransfer.getData('Data');
  // agregamos el elemento de arrastre al contenedor
  target.appendChild(document.getElementById(caja));
  var numeroCajas = $('#contenedor_2 div').length;
  if (numeroCajas > 0) {
    $('.texto').text('');
  } else {
    $('.texto').text('Arrastre los items aqui');
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Listado de Procesos</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_princ" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
      <div id="caja_1" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Mezcla" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_6" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="No Se" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_5" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Etiquetado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_4" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Vaciado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_3" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Llenado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_2" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Esterilizacion" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Contenedor 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_2" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)"><span class="texto">Arrastre los items aquí</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Como haría si los contenedores son agregados dinamicamente? es decir, sino se conoce el `id` del contenedor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo tienes casi hecho. Lo único que te faltaría sería añadir al método `drop` una comprobación que mire si el número de `div`s internos es cero, y si lo es, eliminar el texto. Algo como esto:

```
// si no hay ningún div en el objetivo, se elimina el texto
if (target.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0) {
    target.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Que en tu código se vería así:

```js
function dragstart(caja, event) {
  // el elemento a arrastrar
  //console.log("dragstart");
  event.dataTransfer.setData('Data', caja.id);
}

function drag(target, event) {
  //console.log("drag");
  return false;
}

function dragend(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragend");
  return false;
}

function dragenter(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragenter");
  return false;
}

function dragleave(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragleave");
  return false;
}

function dragover(event) {
  //console.log("dragover");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function drop(target, event) {
  // si no hay ningún div en el objetivo, se elimina el texto
  if (target.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0) {
    target.innerHTML = "";
  }
  // obtenemos los datos
  var caja = event.dataTransfer.getData('Data');
  // agregamos el elemento de arrastre al contenedor
  target.appendChild(document.getElementById(caja));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Listado de Procesos</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_princ" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
      <div id="caja_1" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Mezcla" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_6" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="No Se" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_5" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Etiquetado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_4" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Vaciado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_3" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Llenado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_2" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Esterilizacion" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Contenedor 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_2" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Ahora tendrías otro problema que es que si el texto desaparece y quitas todos los elementos el `div` se queda vacío y es difícil volver a poner elementos dentro (aparte de que igual te interesa volver a poner el texto).

Para ello, conociendo los `id`s de los contenedores podrías hacer esto:

```js
function dragstart(caja, event) {
  // el elemento a arrastrar
  //console.log("dragstart");
  event.dataTransfer.setData('Data', caja.id);
}

function drag(target, event) {
  //console.log("drag");
  return false;
}

function dragend(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragend");
  return false;
}

function dragenter(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragenter");
  return false;
}

function dragleave(target, event) {
  //console.log("dragleave");
  return false;
}

function dragover(event) {
  //console.log("dragover");
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function drop(target, event) {
  // si no hay ningún div en el objetivo, se elimina el texto
  if (target.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0) {
    target.innerHTML = "";
  }
  // obtenemos los datos
  var caja = event.dataTransfer.getData('Data');
  // agregamos el elemento de arrastre al contenedor
  target.appendChild(document.getElementById(caja));

  // mostramos el mensaje (seguramente se puede simplificar)
  var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor_princ");
  if (contenedor.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0) {
    contenedor.innerHTML = "Arrastre los items aquí";
  }
  contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor_2");
  if (contenedor.querySelectorAll("div").length == 0) {
    contenedor.innerHTML = "Arrastre los items aquí";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Listado de Procesos</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_princ" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
      <div id="caja_1" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Mezcla" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_6" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="No Se" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_5" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Etiquetado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_4" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Vaciado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_3" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Llenado" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
      <div id="caja_2" class="col-md-12" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(this, event)" ondrag="drag(this, event)" ondragend="dragend(this, event)">
        <input name="items[]" class="external-event ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); border-color: rgb(0, 115, 183); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative;" value="Esterilizacion" readonly="true" disable="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box box-solid col-md-12">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">Contenedor 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div id="contenedor_2" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="dragenter(this, event)" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragleave="dragleave(this, event)">Arrastre los items aquí
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario lo devuelve al contenedor original y deja vario el "contenedor 1" como vuelvo a colocarle el texto?

Comment: Te estoy poniendo una repuesta para eso 

Comment: un emoticon? por algo tienes 19k de pts! jajaja gracias hermano!

Comment: Estoy en un teléfono móvil, por eso ha salido el emoticono. Voy de camino a casa, cuando llegue limpio la respuesta un poco

Comment: ah. con razon. Ok hermano, gracias. Y los contenedores seran tantos el usuario desea crear, solo el que sera estatico es el `contenedor_princ`, el cual contendra los items originalmente, posteriormente el usuario los repartira a los contenedores del orden que desee.